# if <T> is a type of Class/Constructor then why do we need to extend it to an object over here?

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-generics

If `<T>` is a type of Class/Constructor then why do we need to extend it to an object over here? and how the object we are extending is receiving the Arguments?
Can somebody please explain me what happened in the Decorator Function

```
interface MapLocation {
  lat: number;
  long: number;
}
        
function AddLocation(lat: number, long: number) {
  return <T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }>(
    classConstructor: T
  ) => {
    return class extends classConstructor {
      public mapLocation: MapLocation;
      constructor(...args: any[]) {
        super(...args);
        this.mapLocation = { lat, long };
        }
     };
  };
}
    
@AddLocation(1.234, 1.876)
class Person {
  constructor(public name: string, public age: number) {}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question at all, sorry.  Could you rephrase and clarify?  Maybe call out specific lines that are confusing you?  Also, make sure that you're asking a single question and not multiple.

Comment: Hi @jcalz, I hope you are well and thanks for trying to help.
Basically, I am not able to understand the Decorator Function, why we have extended ,
```return <T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }>(
    classConstructor: T
  ) => {
    return class extends classConstructor {
      public mapLocation: MapLocation;
      constructor(...args: any[]) {
        super(...args);
        this.mapLocation = { lat, long };
      }
    };``` This part, why we have extended <T> with an object

Comment: In TS the keyword `extends` has different meanings in different contexts. When used in a conditional type, `extends` is a form of asymmetrical equality check: `A extends B...` mean `if A is a subtype of B...`, Here the first `extends` is in a type parameter position, so it constrains `T`: it means that `T` needs to be a subtype of { new (...args: any[]): {} } for `AddLocation` to accept it. This also helps inference, whereas the second `extends` is what you usually understand as extending a class. I am pretty sure this is in the handbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }
```

means that T should be a constructor
It may be written more simple as

```
T extends new(...a:any[])=>any
```

Decorator as basically a function, and this allows to disallow to run in over a non-conltructor

```
AddLocation(1, 2)( {} ) // error
class X{
   @AddLocation(1, 2) // error
   f(){}
   @AddLocation(1, 2) // error
   val = 123;
}
```

---

The constructor passes its arguments as argument list

```
function getArgs(...a: any[]) { return a }
let a = getArgs(1, 2, 3) // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(...a) // 1 2 3
```

Comment: thankyou for taking your time and answering. But my question is why are we extending a constructor function to T which is already a constructor function and how the extended constructor function received the arguments which we denoted by ...args

Comment: @KaranBadhwar can you please add `// <-- why this?` in your code so it's easy to understand which part you don't get